# MiniZinc: print out generated constraints?

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc

With MiniZinc, is there a way to print out the programmatically-generated constraints?  For example:

```
constraint exists (i in 1..3) (
     foo != i
);
```

I want to confirm that it is generating:

```
constraint (foo != 1 \/ foo != 2 \/ foo !=3);
```

Answer (score 4):

Although MiniZinc doesn't offer direct printing of constraints as such. MiniZinc does offer the `trace(string: s, var $T: expr)` function. Which can be used to debug your MiniZinc models. `trace` is a print-statement that prints its contents to the command line at the time of evaluation within the compiler. It can thus be used to print the information that you wish to see, but you'll have to format it yourself to show the constraints.

In the case of your exists loop you could use:

```
constraint exists(i in 1..3) (
    trace("foo != \(i)" ++ if i != max(1..3) then " \\/ " else "\n" endif,
    foo != i)
);
```

This will print `foo != 1 \/ foo != 2 \/ foo != 3` to the command line.

Answer (score 3):

To get to know the generated constraints, you can have a look at the generated `FlatZinc` file. The `MiniZinc` compiler translates the `MiniZinc` source into `FlatZinc`. This is then handed over to a solver back-end like `Gecode` of `Chuffed`.

**`MiniZinc` input:**

```
var int: foo;

constraint exists (i in 1..3) (
     foo != i
);

solve satisfy;
```

**Created `FlatZinc`:**

```
var int: foo:: output_var;
var bool: X_INTRODUCED_0_ ::var_is_introduced :: is_defined_var;
var bool: X_INTRODUCED_1_ ::var_is_introduced :: is_defined_var;
var bool: X_INTRODUCED_2_ ::var_is_introduced :: is_defined_var;
constraint array_bool_or([X_INTRODUCED_2_,X_INTRODUCED_1_,X_INTRODUCED_0_],true);
constraint int_ne_reif(foo,1,X_INTRODUCED_0_):: defines_var(X_INTRODUCED_0_);
constraint int_ne_reif(foo,2,X_INTRODUCED_1_):: defines_var(X_INTRODUCED_1_);
constraint int_ne_reif(foo,3,X_INTRODUCED_2_):: defines_var(X_INTRODUCED_2_);
solve  satisfy;
```

To look at the `FlatZinc` form, you can add parameter `--output-fzn-to-stdout` in the `Configuration` tab of the `MiniZinc IDE`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, Axel!  I knew about the FlatZinc output, but thanks for outlining the mechanics.  I still wish I could see the MiniZinc constraints, though...

Answer (score 2):

MiniZinc goes through a whole series of steps when it compiles your expressions down to FlatZinc, so it's not so easy to decide after which step you would print the intermediate representation of the problem.

To look at the generated FlatZinc, you can also simply select "Compile" from the MiniZinc menu rather than using the `--output-fzn-to-stdout` command line option.